# How do I open a Java project (that uses maven) in Eclipse? (Do I use M2E or maven-eclipse-plugin)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to [open this project](https://github.com/p2abcengine/p2abcengine) in Eclipse but not sure how.

I followed the [build instructions](https://github.com/p2abcengine/p2abcengine/wiki/How-to-Build-the-ABC-Engine) and not sure how I tell Eclipse to use Maven as the source control (if required) and then open the Java project so I can step through it.

I discovered that there are [two Maven plugins for Eclipse](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html) (M2E and maven-eclipse-plugin) and not sure which one to choose, since they are incompatible with each other and I need to use.

Comment: which Eclipse verison are you using?

Comment: @Zarathustra Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600

Comment: then you should already have the required plugin.

Comment: maven-eclipse-plugin is obsolete; it generates static Eclipse project files from the POM. Use m2eclipse instead.

Comment: I would just download the J2EE version of Eclipse then do import -> Maven -> Existing maven project if I recall the names correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the OS command line, in the directory of the `pom.xml` file:

```
mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
```

This will create the various eclipse project files. Then in eclipse, in the "Project" pane, right-click > "Import existing project" and navigate to the directory - you'll find it has recognised there's now a project to import.

Comment: It did something, though I'm not sure what... Eclipse didn't open in debug mode so I could step through the code.  My previous attempts at building using MVN as described in the linked page worked fine.  That being said, I assume an output file was generated... maybe a JAR file?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

Right click in the Package Explorer, choose Import.

From the context-menu of the Package Explorer choose import.

In the now open panel search for Existing Maven projects. The rest is pretty much self explaining.